# Find localhost tomcat link of application

Tags: eclipse, jsf

I have found an old jsf project I coded. However, I cannot find the right tomcat localhost link. It seems that everything runs fine, like:

```
Sep 15, 2014 10:02:13 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
Sep 15, 2014 10:02:14 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
Warnung: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:TestProject' did not find a matching property.
Sep 15, 2014 10:02:14 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
Information: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Sep 15, 2014 10:02:14 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
Information: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Sep 15, 2014 10:02:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
Information: Initialization processed in 1790 ms
Sep 15, 2014 10:02:14 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
Information: Starting service Catalina
Sep 15, 2014 10:02:14 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
Information: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
Sep 15, 2014 10:02:16 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator createSecureRandom
Information: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [123] milliseconds.
Sep 15, 2014 10:02:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
Information: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Sep 15, 2014 10:02:28 PM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextInitialized
Information: Mojarra 2.2.0-m08 (-SNAPSHOT 20130107-2105 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.0-m08@11337) für Kontext '/TestProject' wird initialisiert.
Information: Mojarra 2.2.0-m08 (-SNAPSHOT 20130107-2105 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.0-m08@11337) für Kontext '/TestProject' wird initialisiert.
Sep 15, 2014 10:02:29 PM com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderFactory createInstance
Information: JSF1048: PostConstruct/PreDestroy-Annotationen vorhanden.  Verwaltete Bean-Methoden, die mit diesen Annotationen markiert sind, lassen die entsprechenden Annotationen verarbeiten.
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.hibernate.validator.util.Version).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Sep 15, 2014 10:02:31 PM org.primefaces.webapp.PostConstructApplicationEventListener processEvent
Information: Running on PrimeFaces 3.5
Sep 15, 2014 10:02:32 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
Information: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Sep 15, 2014 10:02:32 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
Information: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Sep 15, 2014 10:02:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
Information: Server startup in 17609 ms
```

However, I do not know how to open the `index.xhtml` in this folder:

[image]

I thought that the goes like that:

`http://localhost:8080/TestProject/site/public/master/index.xhtml`

However, I get:

```
HTTP Status 404 

type Status report

message /TestProject/site/public/master/index.xhtml

description The requested resource is not available.
```

Is there any way to find out the correct URL in eclipse?

I really appreciate your replies!

Comment: The web root folder name of "webapp" is recognizable as a Maven-configured project, not a Eclipse-configured project (which uses "WebContent" as web root folder name instead). Eclipse has builtin Maven support. Did you import it as Maven project or at least convert it to Maven project? Are you using Maven? (if so, retag accordingly). Otherwise seeing the full base project folder structure would be more helpful.

Comment: @BalusCYes I am using maven. Can the URL be seen from the `pom.xml`? Or is it already correct and it just does not work of any other problem ,(